# .NET 5 HttpClient cannot GET html content page - http 500

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-5, html-content-extraction

I'm trying to use HttpClient to get html content of a page.
to try the method I tested with the google URL, and it's working, I receive the content of my html page.
but with url I want, impossible to get a content. I have each time a return code http 500.
the problem is that, I can get the content of my file with POSTMAN or even with python but impossible with .NET5

does anyone have an idea ?
thank you in advance.

```
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.naeu.playblackdesert.com/fr-FR/Adventure/Profile?profileTarget=tbXSK7e39Sb3U3yPi7UDjjSeXLzr0HZbr%2bvZQYvtEENKNEz6zPFwtpkvp0pIir%2fk%2fWk7JFLXKICyzqEBwajIrTCHQPFH4MRyBkor2fVeMAb8hNGoasy8HtBiHlcoWN1xRsmmYjVt6WbJg2ocvr%2fbsQk2sbjKeD5a7VqgreAH0ztzMvoFqk7Z%2fZ7L4USyu5Up");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }

            catch(HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");   
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the User-Agent like this.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# console program");
```

Before the line HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync

Comment: I modified the header with the value you recommended and it works :) 
But if I use an API, what should I put as value for my "User-Agent" ?

Comment: see the documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent some servers serve up different page (data) depending on the user-Agent value, some do not. It should be fine to leave it as is if you do not care and you are happy with what the server is giving you now.

Comment: @Kujima if this has worked and is the answer would you be able to mark it as the answer please. thanks